# what do these two lines from visualCaptcha-php-master mean

Tags: php, composer-php, slim

**index.php**

```
//Initialise Slim
$composer = json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/../composer.json');
$app = new \Slim\Slim(
 array(
  'verion'=>$composer->version,
  'debug'=>false,
  'mode'=>'production'
 )
);
```

I am learning how to add visualcaptcha to our login, but having trouble understanding what these lines mean.

This is how I would read it, get the content of `composer.json` and turn it into an array. So now the `$composer` has all the components that are needed for app app to work. Here is the tricky bit, I don't understand why is `new \Slim\Slim(...)`? Also I made an assumption that it is an relative path to the Slim Framework.

I read this [link](https://www.codementor.io/php/tutorial/composer-install-php-dependency-manager) to understand more about `composer` and this [link](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/tutorial/first-app.html) about `slim framework`. But still having trouble understanding this. Maybe I am used to javascript or java and having trouble with other alternatives implementations.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://docs.slimframework.com/configuration/overview/

Comment: Thanks chillNUT. So it is instantiating multiple settings, but it does not explain why it has `\' in front of Slim and two `Slim`?

Comment: Fair enough, based on your question I couldn't tell that that is what you were asking about. It denotes `namespacing`, which you can read more about here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: No you were right from the beginning, your first link did explain the inner part of the code. Now I realise I was also asking about the `namespacing`. anyway I can read these two lines. Cheers, this is really helpful.